# Alt + arrow keys executing odd actions in vim, only in tmux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, vim, tmux

I recently noticed Alt (meta) + arrow keys in my vim executes certain actions, but *only if in tmux* for some reason.

- Alt+Left: Deletes 3 lines. Equivalent to vim `d3d` but works in INSERT mode.
- Alt+Right: Deletes 3 lines INSERT line above. Equivalent to vim `d3dO`.
- Alt+Up: Go to end of line, INSERT. Equivalent to vim `A`.
- Alt+Down: Go back 3 WORDS. Equivalent to vim `3B`.

I have not made any related key bindings in my `.tmux.conf` or `.vimrc`. These commands aren't in vim register either. What is going on here? What configured these commands?

#### System Info

- vim: 8.2.3582
- tmux: 3.2_a
- Arch Linux

INSERT mode CTRL-V

```
Alt+Left    ^[[1;3D
Alt+Right   ^[[1;3C
Alt+Up      ^[[1;3A
Alt+Down    ^[[1;3B
```

environment variable

```
:echo $TERM
tmux-256color
```

Comment: In Vim, enter insert mode and press `<C-v>`, followed by `<A-Left>`, followed by `<CR>`. Do the same for each combo and add a screenshot to your question.

Comment: It sounds like your `TERM` environment variable is not set correctly and Vim isn't understanding the escape sequences your arrow keys send.

Comment: @romainl Added more relevant info

Comment: Comparing your four bullet points to the four `<C-v>` outputs should give you a hint of what is happening. The odds that doing the same `<C-v>` dance *outside* of tmux having a different result are pretty high. Could you do it and add the result to your post?

Comment: What does "`:echo $TERM`" inside Vim show?

Comment: @romainl They are the same unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that vim was executing terminal codes as commands (happens with Ctrl + arrow keys as well). This happens because base vim only supports `xterm` fully. For other terminals, [modified arrow keys must be set manually](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/9009):

```
execute "silent! set <xUp>=\<Esc>[@;*A"
execute "silent! set <xDown>=\<Esc>[@;*B"
execute "silent! set <xRight>=\<Esc>[@;*C"
execute "silent! set <xLeft>=\<Esc>[@;*D"
```

You can read more about this with `:help tmux-integration` and `arrow_modifiers`.